# auto-ml-forecasting-many-models retrieve training results

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-rest-api, azureml-python-sdk

I'm following the Python SDK tutorial for training many models: Here a [link](https://github.com/azure/machinelearningnotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/forecasting-many-models/auto-ml-forecasting-many-models.ipynb) to the notebook

So everything is working fine, but now I'm interested in the training results. When I check the Azure ML Studio I can see the pipeline steps as followed: [training pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYAyi.png).

In the outputs directory of mm-models train I do not get the information I need. But if I check the child-jobs I go down in granularity [child-jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLNmw.png).

Here I can see the trained models and their hyper-parameters for example for the partitioned entities which I want to forecast. So for example a specific product in a certain region. [models for a partitioned entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHuhn.png)

Now what I want now is from the Python SDK (or in general programatically) retrieve the information stored in this child-jobs which I can access via the Azure ML Studio GUI such as cross-validation forecasts or measures for explainability such as these: [Azure ML GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7dIs.png).

I can see that this information is stored in the output folder of the child-jobs: [Output + logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1rUw.png)

I can't figure out from the Documentation of the Python SDK how to retrieve these results. I also tried to get the results from a child-job via the Rest API following this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/batchservice/job/get?tabs=HTTP). The output that I got looks like this: [error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugefY.png) Additionally I would not know how to get all the IDs from the child jobs from within the python SDK.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This class **ManyModelLocalInferencing** provides methods for downloading and running inference on many models (forecasting) trained with [**ParallelRunStep**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-contrib-pipeline-steps/azureml.contrib.pipeline.steps.parallelrunstep?view=azure-ml-py)

**Constructor**

- *init*_(self, experiment, training_run_id, cv_output_path, inference_output_path): initializes the class with the following arguments:

  - experiment: the experiment object that the training run is associated with.
  - training_run_id: the ID of the training run associated with the many models.
    cv_output_path: the path where the cross-validation results and downloaded models will be saved.
  - inference_output_path: the path where the inference results will be saved.

**Methods**

- download_best_models(self): downloads the best models for each time series object based on the cross-validation results. The best models are saved in the cv_output_path directory. This method also saves a summary of the downloaded models in the cv_output_path directory.
- local_inferencing(self, test_set: pd.DataFrame): runs inference on the downloaded models using the input test set. The resulting forecast, quantile and rolling forecast results are saved in the inference_output_path directory.

**Attributes**

- models_downloaded: a boolean value indicating whether the models have been downloaded.

**External Dependencies**

- os: Python built-in module for interacting with the file system.
- json: Python built-in module for working with JSON data.
- pandas: an open-source data analysis and manipulation tool.
- azureml.pipeline.core.PipelineRun: Azure Machine Learning Python SDK module for managing pipeline runs.
- sklearn.externals.joblib: a set of tools to provide lightweight pipelining in Python, particularly for large numpy arrays.

**Note**
The documentation assumes that the class is used in a larger context, where the following variables are defined:

- time_series_id_column_names: a string that represents the name of the column containing the time series IDs.
- label_column_name: a string that represents the name of the column containing the label.

```py
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
from azureml.pipeline.core import PipelineRun
from sklearn.externals import joblib


class ManyModelLocalInferencing:
    
    def __init__(self, experiment, training_run_id, cv_output_path, inference_output_path):
        """
        Initializes the ManyModelLocalInferencing class.
        
        Parameters:
        experiment (azureml.core.Experiment): The experiment object that contains the training run.
        training_run_id (str): The ID of the training run.
        cv_output_path (str): The path to the directory where the best models will be saved.
        inference_output_path (str): The path to the directory where the results of local inferencing will be saved.
        """
        self.experiment = experiment
        self.training_run_id = training_run_id
        self.cv_output_path = cv_output_path
        self.inference_output_path = inference_output_path
        self.models_downloaded = False
        self.results = dict()
        
    def download_best_models(self):
        """
        Downloads the best models for each time series object from the Azure ML run and saves them locally.
        """
        # get the many models training pipeline run
        pipeline = PipelineRun(experiment=self.experiment, run_id=self.training_run_id)

        # find the child runs for the many models training step
        many_models_runs = []
        many_models_train_step = pipeline.find_step_run("many-models-train")[0]
        for run_name in many_models_train_step.get_children():
            many_models_runs.append(run_name)
        

        # create the output directories if they don't exist
        for path in [self.cv_output_path, self.inference_output_path]:
            os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
            print(f"a new directory '{path}' is created!")

        # download the best models for each time series object
        summary = []
        for run in many_models_runs:
            best_model = run.get_best_child()

            try:
                best_model.download_file("forecast_table", output_file_path=self.cv_output_path)
                with open(f'{self.cv_output_path}/forecast_table', "r") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error downloading for run {run.id}: {str(e)}")
                continue

            grain_names = '_'.join(data.get('data')[0].get('grain_value_list')[0])
            run_preprocessor = best_model.properties['run_preprocessor']
            run_algorithm = best_model.properties['run_algorithm']
            score = best_model.properties["score"]

            # check if there is a previous best model for this time series object
            previous_summary = pd.DataFrame(
                summary, columns=[time_series_id_column_names,"preprocessor","algorithm","score"]
            ).query(f"{time_series_id_column_names} == '{grain_names}'")
            if not previous_summary.empty:
                previous_score = previous_summary.score.min()
            else:
                previous_score = None

            # download the best model if it is better than the previous best model
            if previous_score is None or score < previous_score or not os.path.exists(f"{self.cv_output_path}/{grain_names}"):
                try:
                    best_model.download_files(output_directory=f"{self.cv_output_path}/{grain_names}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error downloading model files for run {run.id}: {str(e)}")
                    continue

            summary.append({
                time_series_id_column_names:grain_names, 
                "preprocessor": run_preprocessor,
                "algorithm": run_algorithm,
                "score": score
            })

        # save the summary to a file
        summary_df = pd.DataFrame(summary).groupby(time_series_id_column_names).min()
        summary_df.to_csv(f"{self.cv_output_path}/summary.csv")
        os.remove(f'{self.cv_output_path}/forecast_table')
        
        self.models_downloaded = True
        
    def local_inferencing(self, test_set: pd.DataFrame):
        if not self.models_downloaded:
            print(
                "Models have not been downloaded. Calling download_best_models first."
            )
            self.download_best_models()

        forecast_results = pd.DataFrame()
        quantile_result_list = []
        rolling_result_list = []
        
        for sku in test_set[time_series_id_column_names].unique():

            test_ = test_set[test_set[time_series_id_column_names] == sku]
            fitted_model = joblib.load(f"{self.cv_output_path}/{sku}/outputs/model.pkl")
            model_response = fitted_model.forecast(X_pred=test_)[1]
            model_response[label_column_name] = test_[label_column_name].values
            forecast_results = forecast_results.append(model_response)
            
            X_test = test_set[test_set[time_series_id_column_names] == sku]
            y_test = X_test.pop(label_column_name).values  
            
            fitted_model.quantiles = [0.05, 0.5, 0.95]
            quantile_result_list.append(fitted_model.forecast_quantiles(
                X_test
            ))

            # Make a rolling forecast, advancing the forecast origin by 1 period on each iteration through the test set
            rolling_result_list.append(fitted_model.rolling_forecast(
                X_test, y_test, step=1, ignore_data_errors=True
            ))
    
        self.results["forecast_results"] = forecast_results
        self.results["quantile_results"] = pd.concat(quantile_result_list, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
        self.results["rolling_results"] = pd.concat(rolling_result_list, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
        
        for key, value in self.results.items():
            print(f'saving {key}')
            value.to_csv(f"{self.inference_output_path}/{key}.csv")
```